# Is "-fx-shape" compatible with "-fx-background-image"?

Tags: css, svg, javafx-2

I want to apply a texture to a custom shape. I thought that this would work:

```
.myTextureShape {
-fx-shape: "M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z";
-fx-background-image: url("resources/texture_bg.png");
-fx-background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

But it does not! I get the correct shape but without the texture. All my other regions are correctly texturized so I know that the syntaxe is correct. I guess it's because they are rectangular by default.

If I use the following style instead:

```
.myTextureShape {
 -fx-shape: "M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z";
 -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Then I get a correct red background.

If both attributes are incompatible, how can I apply a texture to a custom SVG-pathed-shape?

P.S: My texture PNG file, is a small 10*10 raster that I repeat to fill my regions with.

Comment: Does it work if you don't set `-fx-shape` and just leave it as a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, without -fx-shape the background image is applied to the whole rectangle.

Comment: Issue tracker link: [RT-28825 -fx-shape not compatible with -fx-background-image](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28825)

Comment: Indeed, that is the bug I created after the nice answer of @MartinTurjak. I'll add the link to my post. According to David Grieve, who's is charge of the bug, it seams that texturazing a SVGPathed-shape through CSS works in JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am concerned `-fx-shape` and `-fx-background-image` don't work together.
JavaFX CSS offers a lot of styling options ... however there are some limitations and some things are only possible with programming. JavaFX CSS uses `impl_setShape()` to coarse the Region class to the defined shape (which is market as deprecated in the api but you can still try it out in javafx 2.2 - which I am using at the moment). Adding the background image ignores the shape and fills the whole pane/region, the same happens if you use addChildren to add ImageView objects into it. So - the css string will not translate into the result you would like.

So I can think of at least 2 ways of applying a pattern to a custom SVGPath shape.
The one I would use is done with ImagePattern. First build the shape like this

```
SVGPath shape = new SVGPath();
shape.setContent("M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z");
```

or using shape builder

```
SVGPath shape = SVGPathBuilder.create()
    .content("M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z")
    .build();
```

and then set the image pattern as fill

```
Image img = new Image("myjavafxapp/resources/texture_bg.png");
shape.setFill(new ImagePattern(img,0,0,10,10,false));
```

An alternative would use clipping (adding a custom shape clip to a pane with -fx-background-image set in the css style), which would look somewhat like this

```
Pane test = new Pane(); 
test.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"myjavafxapp/res/index.jpeg\");");
SVGPath shape = new SVGPath();
shape.setContent("M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z");
test.setClip(shape);
```

One of these should do the trick - you get your shape with the textured background. This is the equivalent to what you would expect from a Region or Pane class with style

```
.myTextureShape {
    -fx-shape: "M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z";
    -fx-scale-shape: false;
    -fx-background-image: url("myjavafxapp/resources/texture_bg.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat; 
}
```

So the SVGPath shape is like all Shape classes nonresizable, in contrast to Region/Pane, this is why I set here the `-fx-scale-shape` attribute to false. The way you had it was with the default setting - which is setting it to true - which makes the shape fill out the whole parent object ... from which I guess that this would be also your desired result. ... there are now again multiple ways of making the shape scale to the parent object.

I got it to work using Group to embed the shape and with a method translating the group (the image size needs to be adjusted in the ImagePattern, so that the texture doesn't scale with the shape). I'm adding a tiny working app, which I used to see on the above example if I remember everything correctly. (if you would like the shape to scale proportionally, you use the same scale factor instead of scalex and sclaey in the addScale method)

```
    package myjavafxapp;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
    import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPathBuilder;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.paint.*;
    import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
    import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    /**
     * @author martint
     */
    public class MyJavaFXApp extends Application {

            private final static String svg = "M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z";
            private SVGPath shape;
            private Image img;
            private Pane resizePane;
            private Group shapeGroup;
            private Node content;

        @Override
        public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

            //build the SVGPath shape
            shape = SVGPathBuilder.create().content(svg).build();
            img = new Image("myjavafxapp/res/index.jpeg");
            resizePane = new Pane();
            shapeGroup = new Group();
            resizePane.getChildren().add(shapeGroup);

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(resizePane);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200); 
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            //fill node content
            content = nodeCont();
            shapeGroup.getChildren().add(content);
            //resizing listening
            resizePane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                                    addScaling();
                            }});
            resizePane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                                    addScaling();
                            }});
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {          
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    addScaling();
                            }
                    });
            }
            private Node nodeCont() {
                    Group cont = new Group();
                    cont.getChildren().add(shape);
                    return cont;
            }
            private void addScaling() {
                    shapeGroup.getTransforms().clear();           
                    //shape boundary
                    double cx = content.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
                    double cy = content.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
                    //resizePane boundary
                    double px = resizePane.getWidth();
                    double py = resizePane.getHeight();
                    //if pane set
                    if (px > 0.0 && py > 0.0) {
                            //scale
                            double scalex = px/cx;
                            double scaley = py/cy;
                            //center
                            double centerx = 0.5 * (px - cx*scalex);
                            double centery = 0.5 * (py - cy*scaley);            
                            //transform
                            shapeGroup.getTransforms().add(new Translate(centerx, centery));
                            shapeGroup.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scalex, scaley));
                            shape.setFill(new ImagePattern(img,0,0,10/scalex,10/scaley,false));
                    }
            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    launch(args);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Bug [RT-28825](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28825) says that  this is possible in JavaFX 8. My experiencing it was with 2.2.6. What version did you use?

Comment: I am using the latest version of javafx, which I believe is 2.2.7. I haven't tried the early access of JDK8 yet, so I don't know if it includes an improved javafx css already, but their roadmap says JDK8 will include javafx 8. Looking forward for 8's improved css and html5 support - but until then my workaround should do it for you =) But I will add stuff to my answer when I figure out something new.

Answer (score 5):

The inablity to apply a background texture to a custom shape via css was a [platform bug](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28825) with JavaFX 2.2 (Java 7).

In Java 8, the platform bug is fixed.

Sample css:

```
/** 
 * file textured-shape.css
 * place in same directory as TexturedShape.java and ensure build system copies 
 * this file to the build output directory.
 */
.textured-shape {
  /** (a square with the bottom triangle chunk taken out of it) */
  -fx-shape: "M0 0 L0 50 L25 25 L50 50 L50 0 Z";
  -fx-background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tooschee/misc/128/Present-icon.png');
  /** 
   * Image license:  
   *   CC Attribution-Noncommercial 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/
   *   Buy commercial license here: http://tooschee.com/portfolio?worksCategory=icons
   */
}
```

Sample App:

```
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TexturedShape extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(128, 128);
    pane.getStyleClass().add("textured-shape");

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(
      getClass().getResource("textured-shape.css").toExternalForm()
    );
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Running the sample code on Java 7, the shape is not applied to the background texture:

[image: java7sample]

Running the same sample code on [Java 8b80](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html), the shape is applied to the background texture:

[image: java8sample]